# Is it possible to remove the right "code overview" from Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I've Googled, but partly because I have no idea what to call it, I have no idea how to remove it. I never use it, and on my laptop screen it takes up a lot of room, especially with multiple column views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Under the `View` menu there is an option to `Show/Hide Minimap` (at least, under Linux and Mac).

Comment: You can also disable it as a default (rather than per session), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877319/sublime-text-2-hide-minimap-by-default