# Sublime Text 2 - hide minimap by default

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a setting to hide the minimap by default?

It's inconvenient to `View > Hide Minimap` for every window I open.

Comment: @alldani I'm using `"hide_minimap": true,` on ST3

Comment: Actually, try both. See my [Preferences](https://github.com/mreq/dotfiles/blob/master/subl/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can hide the minimap by default by adding

```
 "show_minimap": false
```

to your User Settings file *(Preferences > Settings - User)*

Comment: Does that realy work for you? Does not for me on Ubuntu 12.04 and Sublime 2217

Comment: @BobbyNorton Yup. I use it and it works ok for me. I'm on OSX 10.7.5 and Sublime 2220

Comment: Comments below [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14390452/575945) seems to be suggesting the same thing. As it is pointed out there - this setting works only for newly opened files. The current views with minimaps shown won't be updated.

Comment: Does not work on Mac OS X (10.8.5), Sublime Text 2 (build 2221).

Comment: Also doesn't work on Mac OS X (10.9.2), Sublime Text 3 (build 3059).

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac OS X (10.9.5), Sublime Text 3 (build 3065).

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, Sublime Text 3 (build 3114)

Answer (score 15):

You can acces the "View : Toggle Minimap" command via the command palette (Command + Maj + P on mac os) + Enter

Or maybe defining a macro that you can execute when opening a file.

Comment: Do you know how to register the macro to execute when opening a file?

Comment: From the official documentation : http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html. There are steps to record a macro, save it to a file and bind it to some key combination. Given that you should be able to write a script that opens your file and launches your macro.

Comment: OK, so you meant that opening the file is part of the macro.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work since the only command available is to toggle_minimap, not to hide. Same happens for the menu. [This plugin](https://github.com/pcorey/sublime-hide-menu/blob/master/sublime-hide-menu.py) toggles the menu on startup, which hides it unless you have another sublime window open. There should be a show and a hide command for every toggle command, but that is not the case. If someone figures out how to check if the minimap/menu is showing, we can fake show/hide with toggle, but I haven't found that either.

Comment: @Jorge Bucaran Ctrl + shift + P on windows

Comment: @YashGupta Thanks. I still don't understand what is `Maj` though. Is that correctly spelled?

Comment: Yeah it is...`majuscule` (french?) meaning `capital`

Answer (score 10):

For Ubuntu 12.04 Sublime 2221, adding

```
"hide_minimap": true
```

to your User Settings file (Preferences > Settings - User)

Comment: oesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, Sublime Text 3 (build 3114)