# Sublime Text 2: disable document preview

Tags: navigation, sublimetext2

I tried searching for this, but there's a different feature in SublimeText that people call "preview", so I couldn't find any relevant info.

How do I disable the preview navigation image that's displayed within SublimeText2 when a document is open? Also, what is this feature called?

[image]

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is called the "Minimap" in Sublime Text. To disable it, go to `View -> Hide Minimap` in the menus.

Comment: OMG yes! Thank you! What a terrible name for this feature—I never would have guessed :/ I figured it would be somewhere in preferences. Is there a way to disable it everywhere? (I have a bunch of files open, and it only affected the "active" file)

Comment: You can add the line `"show_minimap": false` to your settings file (Preferences -> Settings - User), but that will only work for any new windows/tabs you open. I'm not sure that there's a way to turn it off across all currently running tabs.

Comment: This does not work anymore? Any idea what the setting has changed to?

Comment: @kapad The setting is still there for me in the latest version 2.0.2. Are you using Sublime Text 2 or 3? 3 is still in beta, this option may not be available.

Comment: Using the same version. Build 2221. Make the change in the user settings file. `"show_minimap":false` Does not have any effect. I have also tried `"hide_minimap":true`, but this setting also did not seem to work.

Comment: @jacob: Preview is a terrible name for that feature… because it's not previewing anything — it's just showing literally the same thing as the code view, but scaled down.  “Overview” might be an acceptable term, but “minimap” is more specific; it's a scaled-down image of a larger area (a map) and it's small, off to the side.  “Minimap” is also a well-known UX term, originating from video games.

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like a keyboard shortcut to toggle this, you can create one by adding this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+m"], "command": "toggle_minimap" }
```

...to your `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` file. This sets it to the sequence Ctrl+K followed by Ctrl+M, which I chose just because it's similar to the shortcut (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B) which toggles the sidebar, but you can set it to whatever you like.

Comment: You saved my world from apocalypse :P

Comment: This is a great easy way to be able to toggle the minimap on and off when desired. I use CTRL+K,CTRL+B very frequently!