# Sublime Text 2: Disable 'Goto Anything' Preview

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there a way to disable the document preview when using Goto Anything / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Sublime Text 2?

I've done a lot of searching but the most recent information I've found seems to be a bit old (such as http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5895) and for the most part only related to disabling preview from a single click in the sidebar.

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open files by typing in their path, but having a dozen or so files flash open for a second is annoying; plus, frequently I'm typing in a path from the file open in the current tab, and once preview comes up I can't see the path any more.

Thanks!

Comment: does setting `"animation_enabled": false` in your settings do anything? This is an ST3-only feature...

Comment: @MattDMo Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: Both link related this problem please see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726601/sublime-text-2s-goto-anything-or-instant-search-for-emacs


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390444/sublime-text-2-disable-document-preview

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links! Unfortunately they aren't actually related... While the first does mention Goto Anything, it's asking how to get that functionality in Emacs, and the second is asking how to disable the minimap.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely positive you really can disable it entirely, as it is something that works as part of the editor.

The only settings related to the preview I can find are `"preview_on_click"` and it specifically makes mention of the sidebar. I am not aware of this having any effect on the goto anything overlay.

The one other thing dealing with the goto anything overlay and previews, is the `"binary_file_patterns"` setting, but this will probably tell st2 to treat any file you specify in there as binary... not sure we want that.

Comment: The first part of your answer, i.e. 'not possible', may be the first accurate answer to this question, but the rest isn't really helpful.  The whole point of the question is to find a way to make goto anything more usable.  If simply not using it was a solution, then there would be no question.