# Disable Sublime Text Minimap for a specific syntax

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm trying to find a way to disable Sublime Text 3's minimap for a single syntax (Markdown) only and I'm not having much luck.

I've found a lot of references to adding `"show_minimap": false,` to your preferences both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877319/sublime-text-2-hide-minimap-by-default) and [elsewhere](http://gistpages.com/2013/08/21/hide_minimap_in_sublime_text) but it doesn't seem to do anything regardless of whether I put it in `Markdown.sublime-settings` or `Preferences.sublime-settings` (I am restarting Sublime Text after changing the setting just to be safe).

The `View/Hide Minimap` menu item works globally but I can't set it for a specific syntax.

In most of the threads I've found I see some people saying that the setting doesn't work for them with other people saying it does but none of them seem to have an answer why and how you might fix it.

Has the syntax for that setting changed or has it simply been removed? I don't see it mentioned in the unofficial documentation.

If it does (still) exist is it something you can apply to a specific syntax or does it have to be a global setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried both `"hide_minimap": true` and `"show_minimap": false` (alone and in combination) with ST2 2.0.2 and ST3 Build 3056 on XP, and nothing seems to work. I don't know the versions/platforms the answerers/commenters on your linked questions were using, but it seems that either the behavior was somehow removed recently, or it's platform-specific (maybe a little of both). I went back through the changelogs for [ST2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), [ST3 Public Beta](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), and the [ST3 dev builds](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) and found a number of references to the minimap, but nothing to indicate that the functionality you're looking for had been removed intentionally.

We don't know if it makes a difference to the developer, but the community maintains an [issue tracker](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues) on GitHub for things like this. Feel free to [submit](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/new) a new issue, with as much information as possible about what you've tried and the platform(s) and version(s) used, and we'll see where it goes.

---

If you're the plugin-writing type, there theoretically is a way around this, though. You could write an event listener that checks the scope of any newly-opened files, and if it matches `text.html.markdown` (or whichever type(s) of file for which you'd like to have the minimap hidden), it could execute the `toggle_minimap` command, which is what is fired when you select `View -> Hide Minimap`.

I'm working on that plugin, but it's not coming along very quickly. I'll report back if I can get it to work.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I really appreciate your help! It's strange that this setting apparently worked at some version and/or on some platform but was undocumented and possibly removed. Seems like a really useful feature. I'm not the plugin writing type quite yet, but I'll toss it into my someday/maybe list, I'll also throw a post up on the issue tracker as well. Thanks for the info and the links!

Answer (score 0):

In OS X, Sublime text 3 try:
<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

In Windows perhaps:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>